# Redundant Reference Column in Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, dbcontext, ef-fluent-api

The scenario is:

- There are multiple users
- There are multiple images

Each image can belong to multiple users and each user can have multiple images.

For the many-to-many relationship I created a separate class and used FluentAPI.

The classes are the followings:

**User**

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public IEnumerable<UsersImages> UsersImages { get; set; }
}
```

**Image**

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<UsersImages> UsersImages { get; set; }
}
```

**UsersImages**

```
public class UsersImages
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }        
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public AppUser TheUser { get; set; }
    public Image TheImage { get; set; }
}
```

**The whole AppDbContext code**

```
public class SiteDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public SiteDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UsersImages>()
            .HasKey(us => new { us.UserId, us.ImageId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UsersImages>()
            .HasOne(us => us.TheUser)
            .WithMany(u => u.UsersImages)
            .HasForeignKey(us => us.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UsersImages>()
            .HasOne(us => us.TheImage)
            .WithMany(s => s.UsersImages)
            .HasForeignKey(us => us.ImageId);
    }
}
```

**Now the issue is**

By creating a migration I get the following code:

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Image",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                ImageUrl = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                AppUserId = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Image", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Image_AspNetUsers_AppUserId",
                    column: x => x.AppUserId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

Why there is **AppUserId** column? (I don't want it)

Thank you guys.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't something not shown here? For instance, `public IEnumerable<Image> Images { get; set; }` in `AppUser` class? Or different fluent configuration than shown?

Comment: No I just copied and pasted it, I double checked it, everything is included.

Comment: Well, the additional column (and FK relationship) must come from somewhere. And "somewhere" is not in this code. Create a new blank console project, add just these classes exactly as they are in the question, and you'll not get that column/foreign key.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. OK I will check it. But this is exactly what makes me confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

My issue was because of a big distraction.

@Ivan.Stoev was right.

At the time of applying the migration, the **AppUser** class was inheriting from an abstract class, who contained this:

```
public IEnumerable<Image> Images { get; set; }
```

Thank you guys for your answers and I am so sorry for my giant mistake.